# How to solve "Conversion to double from struct is not possible" error in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, machine-learning, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to run the code below but I keep getting the "Conversion to double from struct is not possible" error over and over. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with what's wrong with the code. The screenshot of the error is attached.

```
H = [1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

ratio = [.6 .2 .2; .7 .15 .15; .8 .1 .1];

result = zeros(30,1);

counter = 1;

load('inputsKonyaAccesshistoricalTransposeAnn.mat');

load('reanalizKonyaprecipitationhistorical.mat');

I1= inputsKonyaaccessTransposehist';

T= reanalizKonyahistprecipitation';

xdata2=(1:size(I1,1))';

dasddas = bsxfun(@(x,y) interp1(y(~isnan(x)),x(~isnan(x)),y),I1,xdata2);

I = dasddas;

for h_counter = 1:length(H)

    for r_counter =  1:3

        result(counter) = train_netloop(H(h_counter),ratio(r_counter,:),I,T);

        counter = counter + 1;

    end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the output of `train_netloop()` is a structure, which you're trying to save in an array you created with `zeros()`, i.e. a double-array. Since a structure is not a double, this obviously won't work. Try `result = cell(30, 1)` and `result{counter} = train_netloop()`, i.e. storing the results in cells.